# Disabling wls9_async_response.war and wls-wsat.war in weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

How to disable `wls9_async_response.war` and  `wls-wsat.war` in weblogic 12c.
This issue is related to the recently found weblogic vulnerability CVE 2019-2725 .

Answer (score 1):

Stop all your servers.
Rename (or remove) these 2 web applications.
Remove each server's tmp directory under $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/[server name]/tmp
Start your servers

A warning will be displayed in server's log saying that WebLogic is not able to deploye these applications but you can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Collin.
Even after deleting those two war files, when we restart the server some of the files are getting regenerated and below link is accessible.
 
https://<example.com>/_async/AsyncResponseService.

Found some solution here.
Put this in your servers start parameter and restart the server.

-Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true 

Referrence
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webserv_adv/asynch.html

Comment: Did you remove also tmp directories ?

Comment: Don't forget that the best solution is to path your weblogic installation.

Comment: Yes, we removed it from temp dirs.

Comment: stopped the server first.Then deleted the required files.Then started the server. the files are gone completely. Thank you

Comment: It is pointless to delete files in $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/[server name]/tmp as WebLogic will re-create them when it next accesses the offending jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable wls-wsat by using the following setting:

```
-Dweblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.deployed=false
```